Looking for clarification on the process of playing audio files
I've been working on a software project recently that's meant to include an audio player, and my plans for it definitely are to simply use an off-the-shelf player library, and go with that. However, what it's gotten me to thinking is how these actual libraries work, all the way from any raw audio file. Hence, I've taken a little bit of a detour to try and understand this process.
From what I understand about audio playing, there are a couple main steps that need to be done when starting with your average consumer audio file (.mp3, for arguments' sake). I've just had a couple questions regarding this process, and I'll outline those as follows.

As it's a compressed format, it can't just be directly translated to audio data, and hence needs to be decompressed. Evidently, this seems to lead to a Pulse Code Modulation file, which seems to be a file type that can store matrices that correspond to amplitudes and wavelengths of the audio, over time? The part I'm unclear of here is what libraries/tools are used for this. I've had some limited experience with the ffmpeg library, and I'm assuming this is one of the main ways this is done, but I haven't actually seen its capabilities in this area. (Additionally, I feel like this isn't allowed to ask, but, do mainstream streaming services/applications like YouTube or Soundcloud incorporate ffmpeg under the hood?)

Once the file is in a decompressed format like this, how is this data encoded? (Forgive me for the offensively simple comparison, but I'm thinking of this as akin to reading a decompressed image file (as seen in libraries like Pillow). Images are encoded as 2D matrices, each cell giving a specific intensity of grey, or as 3D matrices, each cell giving the r/g/b value.) I'm imagining that decompressed audio files would carry a similar structure, but then leads me to my main confusion here. How are audio files iterated through? With an image, you could very easily draw out an image from the decompressed data by simply iterating over each cell in the matrix and displaying that pixel. Can this be done with audio files too? Simply grab one specific frame, or point in time, of an audio file, and "display" it through any audio output?

Lastly, how would a normal program relay this audio output to a specific device? If we're treating the audio output (a speaker or headphone) as a service, what info is being relayed and at what frequency? Do programs simply constantly relay a stream of data, each packet being a specific part of the audio, to the service?


I'm realising these questions might seem extremely rudimentary and ignorant, but I can't really seem to find too much information on this through simple searching. It seems that this is not only a lot more complicated than I've expected, but also simply uncared for as "there are just libraries to do it". But I'm still a bit curious here, and I'm hoping y'all could shed some light on this. If anything needs to be clarified, I'd be happy to do so.

StackExchange is not a "find the documentation for me" question board. There are plenty of available resources to learn about this topic.

No sane implementation of a music playing library will ever create a decompressed version of the music files. For example,  .mp3 consists of blocks of around 25 milliseconds, which will be be decoded to typically about 4kilobyte in memory.

The topic is quite expansive, you started out good and veered off-course around here:

As it's a compressed format, it can't just be directly translated to
audio data, and hence needs to be decompressed. Evidently, this seems
to lead to a Pulse Code Modulation file, which seems to be a file type
that can store matrices that correspond to amplitudes and wavelengths
of the audio, over time? The part I'm unclear of here is what
libraries/tools are used for this. I've had some limited experience
with the ffmpeg library, and I'm assuming this is one of the main ways
this is done, but I haven't actually seen its capabilities in this
area. (Additionally, I feel like this isn't allowed to ask, but, do
mainstream streaming services/applications like YouTube or Soundcloud
incorporate ffmpeg under the hood?)

The mp3 file doesn't become a PCM (wav) file. It stays an mp3 file. The purpose of the compression is to make storing and transferring the file easier, as it is smaller in size.
Instead, what happens is that the file is split into chunks and those chunks are decompressed in real time, just before the audio is about to be rendered.

Once the file is in a decompressed format like this, how is this data
encoded? (Forgive me for the offensively simple comparison, but I'm
thinking of this as akin to reading a decompressed image file (as seen
in libraries like Pillow). Images are encoded as 2D matrices, each
cell giving a specific intensity of grey, or as 3D matrices, each cell
giving the r/g/b value.) I'm imagining that decompressed audio files
would carry a similar structure, but then leads me to my main
confusion here. How are audio files iterated through? With an image,
you could very easily draw out an image from the decompressed data by
simply iterating over each cell in the matrix and displaying that
pixel. Can this be done with audio files too? Simply grab one specific
frame, or point in time, of an audio file, and "display" it through
any audio output?

The stream is mostly iterated sequentially (unless you seek to a position e.g. like with a seekbar which would usually involve a stream seek). You read data from the stream sequentially, and then parse the data. Initially, each file stream will contain some metadata which will help you decode it. As you read through the stream, you encounter elements known as packets. Those packets contain the compressed audio data. The decoder will compute the timestamp (or read it if it is present) of the packet, so it knows when it should render in relation to the start of the file. Normally the decoder is a few milliseconds to seconds (depending on target lateness) ahead of the renderer and there is some buffering between them.

Lastly, how would a normal program relay this audio output to a
specific device? If we're treating the audio output (a speaker or
headphone) as a service, what info is being relayed and at what
frequency? Do programs simply constantly relay a stream of data, each
packet being a specific part of the audio, to the service?

Here it comes down the digital signal processing theory.
Basically sound as we hear it in our environment is a vibration in the air. Microphones capture this vibration and translate it into some values (normally in the range of 0-255 but it depends). Those values are the amplitude of the vibration (aka PCM - you can feed this data into a speaker directly and it will generate the exact same sound!). At this point you can determine the frequencies of the sound but you need to perform something called a Fourier transform (the exact algorithm used in most audio scenarios is the fast version - FFT). But you don't always need to do that. Mp3 does need a frequency representation, but not all codecs do.
The microphone will translate the vibration through a process called sampling. Sampling has 3 big components:

sampling frequency/rate (how many times the value is read in a second - do not confuse this with sound frequency. This sampling frequency needs to be at least 2x the max frequency of the sound you want to capture see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nyquist%E2%80%93Shannon_sampling_theorem),
sample format (number of bits, if ints or floats are used)
number of channels & their layout (normally 1 or 2 but go up more than that).

This information is very important and will be added to the file header. If it is missing, the file is normally considered invalid or corrupted.
The encoder will then do its magic (intentionally left as a black box here to simplify) and will output your compressed file.
The decoder will then do its magic to get back the raw amplitude values.
Finally, the decompressed sound, which is now PCM, is send to the rendering device via the driver. The OS may perform additional mixing if there are multiple sound sources active at the same time. The device will then recreate the exact amplitudes that were recorded by the microphone because the rendering device vibrates. With the sampling frequency, sample format and number of channels that were used by the microphone, your speaker is now able to reconstruct the initial vibration.
If you want to dig more into how signal sampling and reconstruction works, you can start here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sampling_(signal_processing) and move on to the biography.
Questions from comments:

when you mention packets that are read sequentially from the audio
file, are these sent one by one to the rendering device?

Yes, they are sent one by one to the rendering device, in the order in which they are supposed to be played. As I mentioned, there is some buffering between the decoder and the renderer, if there is a seek in the stream, the buffering needs to be flushed if it is too long.

secondly, how long are these packets (i.e. is this the sound frequency you mentioned earlier)?

The size of the compressed packages depend on the codec being used, you will have to check specifications for that.
You can use this formula to estimate the size of the uncompressed audio sample (the one that will end up in the renderer):
<sampling rate> x <number of bytes per sample> x <number of channels>


also, little bit more tangential of a question, but as this is meant
to be a part of a mini-project, how would one actually interact with
one of these rendering devices directly so that I could actually
manually manipulate these sounds, rather than using a predefined
library that converts entire files to audio outputs

If you are using an OS your reasonable chance is to use something the OS provides. Windows 10/11 has a number of APIs that allow you to do some pretty low level sound manipulations:
MediaStreamSource
AudioGraph
XAudio2
Cross platform there's ffmpeg & ffplay, and vlc, both of which do their own rendering.
If you want an integration of ffmpeg and MediaStreamSource you can check out ffmpeginteropx. This is also a good example for the packet by packet decoding of files.
If you are using some embedded device like an Arduino with a speaker, you will have to check their documentation. Most of the time it boils down to just feeding the raw PCM to the device with some low level function, as if it were some array. Keep in mind that you have to feed those samples fast enough so there's no audible breaks in the output sound. This is why the buffering of the renderer input exists, to make sure there's enough data for smooth playback.

this is some very helpful information, thank you so much! as I expected, it seems to be a lot more complex than I initially imagined it to be, but this actually does a lot to help compartmentalise each of the parts! a couple clarifications on this, when you mention packets that are read sequentially from the audio file, are these sent one by one to the rendering device? secondly, how long are these packets (i.e. is this the sound frequency you mentioned earlier)?

also, little bit more tangential of a question, but as this is meant to be a part of a mini-project, how would one actually interact with one of these rendering devices directly so that I could actually manually manipulate these sounds, rather than using a predefined library that converts entire files to audio outputs

@Daneolog I've edited the answer.

@Daneolog depends on the (os, language) context, but here's the Windows answer https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/_coreaudio/


Images are encoded as 2D matrices, each cell giving a specific intensity of grey, or as 3D matrices, each cell giving the r/g/b value.) I'm imagining that decompressed audio files would carry a similar structure, but then leads me to my main confusion here.

You're almost there: PCM-style audio files are a 1D matrix, each of which carries a sample at a particular amplitude.

what libraries/tools are used for this.

The general term is a "codec". ffmpeg contains a whole load of codecs for various audio and video formats. For mp3 they appear to use https://lame.sourceforge.io/ ; the original Fraunhofer one https://www.iis.fraunhofer.de/en/ff/amm/consumer-electronics/mp3.html has finally had its patents expire, so it may be freely available now somewhere.

Do programs simply constantly relay a stream of data, each packet being a specific part of the audio, to the service?

Pretty much yes. Usually there will be a buffer of a few samples representing a few milliseconds of audio.
